# Laravel custom error message

Tags: error-handling, laravel-5

I am developing a web application using laravel5. I want to remove the default error message and put my custom error message.How do i do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error message? There are thousands.

Comment: As above - what messages do you mean? Validation? 4XX/500 error pages?

Comment: Not validation error.It is a 404 error which occurred when there is an input or action and it says "Whoops,something went wrong..." it is the default error message in laravel

Answer (score 0):

You have to add appropriate error pages in errors view folder - like **503.blade.php**, **500.blade.php** and so on. And then add some logic in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php file`.